# Can Oracle client versions 9 and 11 both be installed on the same machine?

Tags: oracle, oracle-call-interface, odac

I have a program using odac(11.2) and oracle client 11.2. Now I want to deploy it to a box which is already installed a oracle 9i client.

Some existing programs is depend on it so I fear  the new client will harm the existing program. Is this true?  And how can I keep them all working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you install oracle products in a dedicates ORACLE_HOME in different directories (like `/ora/app/oracle/product/9.2` and `/ora/app/oracle/product/11.2`). Then you set the `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$PATH` variables to that directory which will be working fine.

We use many different client versions from 8.1.6 to 11.2 on one machine. Every application has an own shell script setting up the correct environment prior to starting.

Comment: thanks.the actual senario is : 2 asp.net app deplyed in one machine(use IIS 6), use odp 9 and odp 11 respectlly. how can i make this possible? sorry for question not very accurate wrriten.

Comment: I do not know about asp.net. How do they call the libraries? Is there any way to do an "include" or something? If you do not use too new functionality you could also try to use 9i client for your new app, maybe that is working.

Comment: use odac 11 for EF4. the odp 9 is  for interact with a oracle 8 DB. Now things looks not very handy to solve so i abandon this solution.anyway thanks.